# Spivak, Chapter 24, Problem 2(viii): Uniform Convergence of $\{ n(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x})\}$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ = $\{ n(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x})\}$.

In Chapter 24 of Spivak's *Calculus*, we are asked to determine if this sequence converges uniformly to $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ on different intervals.

I just wanted to write my solution below to make sure all the steps are correct. There are two steps in the end that I feel comfortable with but am not totally sure about: one involves the use of L'Hopital's rule, and the other involves the justification for why $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Let's first consider an interval $(a,\infty)$ with $a>0$.

Let's consider first the sequence of functions $\{g_n(x)\}=\{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}\}$.

Note that $g(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)=0$.

Using the Mean Value Theorem with $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$ we have

$$\frac{h(x+1/n)-h(x)}{x+1/n-x}=g'(\alpha)$$

for some $\alpha\in (x,x+1/n)$. Then,

$$h(x+1/n)-h(x)=g_n(x)-g(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}\cdot \frac{1}{n}\tag{1}$$

$$<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}n}$$

From this we see that $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $(a,\infty)$.

Let's go back to $f_n=ng_n$.

**First question:** is it ok to use L'Hopital's rule to compute the following limit

$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+1/n}-\sqrt{x}}{1/n}=(...)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1/n}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

This seems to make sense. Here is a plot of this $f(x)$ (yellow) and $f_n(x)$ for $n$ from 1 to 15.

[image]

Using (1) we have that

$$f_n(x)=n\cdot g_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\alpha}, \alpha\in (x,x+1/n)$$

Thus,

$$0\leq f(x)-f(x_n)\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1/n}}$$

$$\implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (f(x)-f_n(x))=0$$

Therefore, we have uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ to $f$ on $[a,\infty)$.

The question is what happens on $[0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Note that $f(0)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(0)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}$ which doesn't exist.

Therefore, we can rule out (pointwise or uniform) convergence at $0$.

Note that $f(x)$ grows without bounds near $0$, but that each $f_n$ is in fact defined at $0$: $f_n(0)=\sqrt{n}$. Therefore, there is no single number $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have all of the $f_n$ functions close to $f$ at all points near $0$. After all, $f$ grows without bounds near $0$, but every $f_n$ is bounded.

**Second question:** is this explanation of why uniform convergence doesn't occur on $(0,\infty)$ correct?

Hence, we don't have uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$, but we do on any $(a,\infty)$ with $a>0$.

Comment: Use of L'Hoapital rule (taking $t=1/n$ as the *vatiable* is fine. However, computing the limit in this case is easer nice $g_n(x)=\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$ ($f(x)=\sqrt{x}$)  which is basically a differential ration (something of the form $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and as you know, passing to the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (equivalently $1/n\rightarrow0$) yields the derivative of $f$ at $x$. The second question is related to the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not uniform continuous in $(0,\infty)$. RRL gives a more precise argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument for non-uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$ is intuitive.  To make this precise show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}|f_n(x) - f(x) | \neq 0$.

Note that

$$|f_n(x) - f(x) | = \left|n\left(\sqrt{x+\frac1n} -\sqrt{x}\right)- \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right|= \frac{\left|2n\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x+\frac1n} -\sqrt{x}\right)-1\right|}{2\sqrt{x}},$$

and, since $\frac1n\in (0,\infty)$,

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}|f_n(x) - f(x) |\geqslant \frac{\left|2n\sqrt{\frac1n}\left(\sqrt{\frac1n+\frac1n} -\sqrt{\frac1n}\right)-1\right|}{2\sqrt{\frac1n}}= \frac{1 - 2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}\sqrt{n}$$

Since the lower bound on the RHS tends to $+\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ it follows that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}|f_n(x) - f(x) |= +\infty \neq 0$$